# Is the operator with kernel $k(s,t) = \frac{\pi \exp \left( G(s,t) \right)F(s,t)}{(s+t)^2}$ compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Suppose the kernel of an integral operator is given by:
$$k(s,t) = \frac{\pi  \exp \left(-\frac{2 \sqrt{2} |t-s|}{\sqrt{s + t}} \right)(2 \sqrt{s+t}-4 \pi |t-s|)}{(s+t)^2}$$

My question is whether the integral operator
$$K{g(t)}=\int_0^1k(t,s)g(s)ds$$
is compacot or not.

Comment: From where to where?

Comment: $L^2[0,1] \rightarrow L^2[0,1]$

Comment: Then, as written, it isn't even bounded.Just try to apply it to the characteristic function of $[0,\delta]$ with small $\delta>0$.